# Use of same struts html:optionsCollection for difference drop down

Tags: java, struts

I am using `struts 1.1` and I have two drop down which has the same data (drop down list). I have to save the selected two values as varchars in two different columns.
Can I accomplish this with the same map created in the form for both drop downs?

For example below is one drop down which saves the user id and suppose there is another similar drop down which I save the create user id which both use the same populate user list.

```
<html:select property="selectedCancelUserId">
     <html:option value="">-</html:option>
     <html:optionsCollection property="usedByUserList" label="name" value="staffNo"/>
</html:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two different form variables like `selectedCancelUserId` and `selectedCreateUserId` in the form to capture two different inputs from the user. The `usedByUserList` can be used multiple times in the form for display as long you have associated form values with them.

```
 <html:select property="selectedCancelUserId">
       <html:option value="">-</html:option>
       <html:optionsCollection property="usedByUserList" label="name" value="staffNo"/>
 </html:select>

 <html:select property="selectedCreateUserId">
       <html:option value="">-</html:option>
       <html:optionsCollection property="usedByUserList" label="name" value="staffNo"/>
 </html:select>
```